# accessing a webservice through class library in .net3.5 vs2008

Tags: .net, webservice-client, class-library, endpoint

I had a webservice which i was directly accessing from my webform. I used a service reference in my wesite and used a serviceclient on my webform which worked fine.

Now i removed the service reference from my website and created a class library hich consumes this webservice the same way usinfg a service reference and service client in the class.

when i try to use this class library now it gives me an error that no default endpoint found for the contract. Also i had changed the namespace of my class library and also changed it in settings and assembly files. the dll still has the old name :( 
I've added a reference of this class library in my website.

where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a WCF service reference into a class library, then you will get an app.config with the binding information created in that class library. Unfortunately when you reference the library, that config information isn't loaded.

You need to copy the  portion of the app.config in the class library to your main application's config area. That will make it available when the service is called.

Answer (score 0):

The service reference still needs to be added to the webform project as well, because the client connects using the settings in the `web.config` of the project that is running, not the class library.

Comment: Thanks very much. adding the service mosdl from class library webconfig to website project resolved the issue.